# Nanospell not working. Is nanospell offline?

Tags: c#, asp.net, tinymce, spell-checking

I have a project which includes the TinyMCE editor.
For the spellchecker i use Nanospell.
Local this works fine.

On my server(live version) i always get those red wiggly red lines.
The language that must be checked is English which is the default language.

When you google for nanospell you also end up with a tinymcespellcheck site which shows the followig message:

**This site is on an older infrastructure that will be decomissioned in the near future.
If you are the site administrator, simply log into your admin panel and migrate to the new V2 infrastrucure.
Please contact us if you have any questions, or read the following guide to learn more.**

Is nanospell not working anymore or do i miss a setting?

my tinymce init:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: "textarea#cn_Contents",
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | forecolor backcolor",
            plugins: "textcolor",
            external_plugins: { "nanospell": "plugin.js" },
            nanospell_server: "asp.net",

            setup: function(editor) {
                editor.on('focus', function(e) {
                    if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() == '<p>Enter your content</p>') {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
                    }
                });
                editor.on('blur', function (e) {
                    if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent() == '') {
                        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>Enter your content</p>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: external_plugins: was wrong.

Comment: external_plugins: is this relative to the aspx or  nanospell folder?
Still not fixed.